# What is the difference between the bind and live methods in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, bind, live

I'm curious to know the differences between the bind and live functions.

To me they seem to be almost identical.

I read [the benefits of live/bind methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748076/using-live-benefits-similar-to-bind), but it didn't tell me about the differences...

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the answer below, readers might want to have a look at this *unbelievably good* [article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/) explaining the difference between `bind`, `live` and `delegate`.

Comment: Update: Since jquery 1.7 - ´live()´ is deprecated in favor for `on()`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

.bind() attacheds events to elements that exist or match the selector at the time the call is made. Any elements created afterwards or that match going forward because the class was changed, will not fire the bound event.

.live() works for existing and future matching elements. Before jQuery 1.4 this was limited to the following events: click, dblclick mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, keydown, keypress, keyup

Comment: For anyone reading this now, `.live()` is no longer limited to the events listed above. The `.live()` event now has support in jQuery 1.4 for all events, including custom events.

Comment: this answer does not really answer the question, see below answer by nickf for the requested explanation

Comment: Bind is just a poor and limited live… why on earth does it still exists ?

Answer (score 89):

In short: `.bind()` will only apply to the items you currently have selected in your jQuery object. `.live()` will apply to all current matching elements, as well as any you might add in the future.

The underlying difference between them is that `live()` makes use of [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). That is, when you click on a button, that button might exist in a `<p>`, in a `<div>`, in a `<body>` element; so in effect, you're actually clicking on all of those elements at the same time.

`live()` works by attaching your event handler to the *document*, not to the *element*. When you click on that button, as illustrated before, the document receives the same click event. It then looks back up the line of elements targeted by the event and checks to see if any of them match your query.

The outcome of this is twofold: firstly, it means that you don't have to continue reapplying events to new elements, since they'll be implicitly added when the event happens. However, more importantly (depending on your situation), it means that your code is much much lighter! If you have 50 `<img>` tags on the page and you run this code:

```
$('img').click(function() { /* doSomething */ });
```

...then that function is *copied* into each of those elements. However, if you had this code:

```
$('img').live('click', function() { /* doSomething */ });
```

...then that function is stored only in one place (on the document), and is applied to whatever matches your query at event time.

Because of this bubbling behaviour though, not all events can be handled this way. As Ichiban noted, these supported events are click, dblclick mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, keydown, keypress, keyup.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of *how* this works.  The jQuery documentation doesn't explain any of this, which seems important for using it.

Comment: @meagar: "Because of this bubbling behaviour though, not all events can be handled this way. As Ichiban noted, these supported events are click, dblclick mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, keydown, keypress, keyup." So now that it works for all events in later versions of jQuery, is it still working by being attached to the body and triggered when the body finally receives the bubbled event, or did that change?

Comment: Great answer! Really helps to understand what goes on in the code. Was actually looking for this. Big +1 from me!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the rationale of why `live()` is a 'lighter' solution.  Yes, in the example, the `click()` handler will be copied 50 times.  But that happens (and the copies are stored) behind the scenes, and it only happens once.  Additionally the execution of the handler function is simpler in that case, since there's no need to inspect where the event came from and match selectors before invoking the actual event handler.  So `live()` is lighter in terms of space and setup time, but slightly heavier in terms of runtime processing.

Comment: Edit:  I'm not even sure it would be copied 50 times; I think what you probably end up with is 50 references to a single copy, with jQuery making clever use of `apply()` and/or `call()` to set the value of `this` appropriately each time the event handler is triggered.  That's how I'd do it anyways.  I suppose checking the source code is the only way to know for sure though.

Comment: aroth - you're completely correct. I was young and stupid when I wrote this answer, but never got around to correcting it.

Comment: @nickf I can learn a lot from your answer , thanks, But I have a question for you ,what you mean is event bubble or event capture ? becuase event bubble goes up but capture goes deep , thanks.

Comment: What I can contribute this answer is **the live() method can only be used on selectors, and can’t be used on
derived wrapped sets.**

Comment: and more is seems `live` triggers the event by the script.not use the event handler.

Answer (score 5):

Bind will bind events to the specified pattern, for all matches in the current DOM at the time you call it. Live will bind events to the specified pattern for the current DOM and to future matches in the DOM, even if it changes.

For example, if you bind $("div").bind("hover", ...) it will apply to all "div"s in the DOM at the time. If you then manipulate the DOM and add an extra "div", it won't have that hover event bound. Using live instead of bind would dispatch the event to the new div as well.

Answer (score 5):

Nice read on this: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/

Is nowadays (since jQuery 1.7) deprecated using the .on() function - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 4):

imagine this scenario:

1. i have several `<img>` elements.

   - `$('img').bind('click', function(){...});`
   - add some extra images (using `get()`, or `html()`, anything)
   - the new images don't have any binding!!

of course, since the new images didn't exist when you did the `$('img')...` at step 2, it didn't bind the event handler to them.

now, if you do this:

1. i have several `<img>` elements.

   - `$('img').live('click', function(){...});`
   - add some extra images (using `get()`, or `html()`, anything)
   - the new images *do* have the binding!!

magic?  just a little.  in fact jQuery binds a generic event handler to another element higher in the DOM tree (body? document? no idea) and lets the event bubble up.  when it gets to the generic handler, it checks if it matches your `live()` events and if so, they're fired, no matter if the element was created before or after the `live()` call.

Answer (score 3):

In adition to what they said, I think it's best to try to stick to `bind` when/where you can and use `live` only when you must.

Comment: You're right.  .live is a must for ajax events, though, right?

Comment: Why do you say that? I've found that live simplifies the code. I'm pretty picky about performance, and it seems fine to me. What's the downside?

Comment: Well, first of all because not all events are available with live(). Secondly, because I think they are harder to manage (no stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropagation), and third because live() surely generates more overhead than bind() (as it looks for changes in the DOM). Maybe not a killer difference, but still. That's why I tend to stick to bind() where possible.

Comment: live() doesn't look for DOM changes, it maintains a list of target selectors and checks them at event time (the events fire on `document`). There is some overhead, but it's very minimal. The real danger is that some uses of `live` can cause garbage collection to fail.

Answer (score 1):

All these jQuery methods are used for attaching events to selectors or elements. But they all are different from each other.

**.bind():** This is the easiest and quick method to bind events. But the issue with bind() is that it doesn’t work for elements added dynamically that matches the same selector. bind() only attach events to the current elements not future element. Above that it also has performance issues when dealing with a large selection.

**.live():** This method overcomes the disadvantage of bind(). It works for dynamically added elements or future elements. Because of its poor performance on large pages, this method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 and you should stop using it. Chaining is not properly supported using this method.

Find out more [here](http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to this after having to debug a bit due to my own silliness. I applied .live() to a class of button on my page, assuming that it would just render out the correct ID I was trying to pass on the query string and do what I wanted to do with the ajax call. My app has dynamically added buttons associated with an inventory item. For instance, drill down categories to the 'COKE' button to add a coke to your order. Drill down from the top again, and add 'BUDLITE' - each time I wanted those items to be entered into a table via an AJAX call.

**However**, since I bound .live() to the entire class of buttons, it would remember each ajax call I had made and re-fire it for each subsequent button! It was a little tricky because I wasn't exactly clear on the difference between bind and live (and the answer above is crystal about it), so I figured I'd put this here just in case somebody was doing a search on this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get the live effect but its kind of nasty.

$(this).unbind('mouseout').bind('mouseout',function(){
});

this will clear the previous and reset the new. It has seemed to work fine for me over time.

Comment: Or you can use proper event delegation, bind the events to `document`, and check the event's target.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between live and livequery is [discussed here](http://www.neeraj.name/blog/articles/882-how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery) .