# jquery Ajax: selector as function param doesn't get logged?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, parameters, console

I don't have a clue why this does not work for me.

I'm calling a this on a linkclick!

```
$('.pagination a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr("data-ajax-link");

    //get classname of container box that should be reloaded
    var box = $(this).parent().parent();

    ajaxLoad(box, page, false);
    console.log(box); //takes some time as well! WHY?

});
```

And here the function that's triggered.

```
function ajaxLoad(targetBox, loadUrl) {

    console.log('start');
    console.log($(targetBox));

    $.ajax({
        url: loadUrl,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html,status) {
            console.log('end');
```

The weird thing I don't get is that `console.log('start')` is logged immediately in my console but `console.log($(targetBox));` is not appear in the console until the success of the ajax function comes back!

why is that? Any idea?

This is the HTML that that is triggering the function.

```
<div class="list wide">        
     <div class="pagination">
          <span>&lt;</span>
          <em>[1]</em>
          <a data-ajax-link="/ajax/render/project/my?page=2" rel="next" href="/my/project/2">2</a>
          <a data-ajax-link="/ajax/render/project/my?page=2" rel="next" href="/my/project/2">&gt;</a>
     </div>
...
```

So the element I'm selecting with parent().parent() is the div.list. So actually .list should be logged immediately when clicking the link.

Comment: I updated my question with some html.

Comment: Well, those weired kind of errors do occur with jquery's ajax. Like one times i just changed the name of the file and it worked. Sometimes i need to dump the complete complete code and write again. I cant see any error in this

Comment: Must be. Check out my updated code. Even if the console.log() call is called outside of the ajaxLoad() function it take until the success come back. ?

Comment: Of coure it will execute after the ajax is complete place it above the function ajaxloader if u want it to be done before ajax ?

Comment: NOPE! doesn't make a difference if I place it above or below the function! If I don't comment out the ajaxLoad() call in my click handler `console.log(box)` is not fired until the success of the ajax comes back -> even if it doesn't correlate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me in this simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmkcG/

Can you update to show the context of this? That is, show this in the context of the function where it's being used to assign to box?

Comment: yeah, I know that's weird. I updated my question with some html.

Comment: Well, I updated my code! THIS IS THE WEIRDEST THING: Even in the click handler the list element doesn't get logged when it's called after ajaxLoad(). If I comment out the ajaxLoad() call it does work immediately.

Comment: Is this perhaps because you're using live() instead of bind()? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937039/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bind-and-live-methods-in-jquery for some discussion.