# $(this).parent().remove(); not working in IE

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why the code below wouldn't work in IE, yet in FF and Chrome it does:

```
$(".remove", document.getElementById("ccusers")).live("click", 
  function () {
     $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

If I try:

```
alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
```

I get the id alerted out in FF & Chrome but not IE.

Any ideas what needs to be done differently?

Comment: What type of element is '#ccusers'? When the DOM tree is formed certain elements get inserted without you knowing (e.g. `tbody` in a table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".remove, #ccusers").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

To make shure you are removing the right parent element up in the tree  and its children you can try this:

```
$(this).parents('theParentYouWantToRemove').remove();
```

You may find this useful: [What is the difference between the bind and live methods in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937039/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bind-and-live-methods-in-jquery)

P.S. I suggest you to use only `$('.remove')` , as I don't see any reason why you are doing `$('.remove, #ccusers')`, as it will actually mean:
 elements`.remove` OR element `#ccusers`,

And by doing: `$('.element' , '#element')` (look at the quotes!) your 'second' element will do **[absolutely NOTHING](http://jsbin.com/ofigus/edit#javascript,html,live)** ! (like many here suggested).

**So my only valid suggestion would be:**

```
$(".remove").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).parents('#ccusers').remove(); // or .parent() as I explained above
});
```

### [DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/usijol/edit#javascript,html,live)

(download and try in IE)

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<div id="ccusers">
    <span>User1</span>
    <span>User2</span>
    <div class="remove">Remove</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(".remove", "#ccusers").live("click", function() {
     $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Works fine for me in IE7, see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/NrKRF/

Answer (score -3):

If you are gunna use jQuery. **Use** jQuery:

```
 $(".remove", "#ccusers").live("click", function () {
       $(this).parent().remove();
 });
```