# click() for ClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, onclick

**UPDATE**: A commenter told me to change some codes, this is the new code and its not working neither.

I'm creating a Facebook-Like chat. It gets the latest messages "Not Read" from a JSON file and it appends the text to an "UL" element vía "LI" into a box. If the box doesn't exist, it creates and attach the text. I want that when I click that div, it hides using margin-bottom negative, and when I click it again it shows by Margin-Bottom:0. Please help me since it's just not working.

```
function showChat(id){
$(this).animate({marginBottom : "0"}).removeClass("hidden_box").addClass("active_box").removeAttr('onclick').click(function(){
       hideChat(Id);
    });

}
function hideChat(id){
$(this).animate({marginBottom : "-270px"}).removeClass("active_box").addClass("hidden_box").click(function(){
       showChat(Id);
    });

}

function getOnJSON(){

//Creating Variables that will be used
var from;var to;var msg_id;var msg_txt;

//Getting the data from the json file
$.getJSON("/ajax/chat.json.php",function(data){

//Repeat for each result
$.each(data.notif, function(i,data){

//Getting a var to info
from = data.from;to = data.to;msg_id = data.id;msg_txt = data.text;

//check if div exists
        if ($("#chat_"+from+"_lp").length === 0){

//If not, create the div
            $("#boxes").append('<div id="chat_'+from+'_lp" class="chat_box hidden_box clickable_box"></div>');

//Add the senders name
            $("#chat_"+from+"_lp").append('<div id="'chat_+from+'_nick" class="chat_name">'+from+'</div>');

//Add the chats UL
            $("#chat_"+from+"_lp").append('<ul id="chat_'+from+'_txt" class="chat_txt"></ul>');

//Add the message text
            $("#chat_"+from+"_lp").append('<li id="' + msg_id + '">'+ msg_txt+'</li>');

//Add event handler for each div
            $('#chat_'+from+'_lp').click(function() {showChat(this);});

//If div exists just add the text
        }else{

//Add the message text
            $("#chat_"+from+"_txt").append('<li id="' + msg_id + '">'+ msg_txt+'</li>');

//Add event handler for each document
            $('#chat_'+from+'_lp').click(function() {showChat(this);});

//Close If
        }
//Close data for each item      
    });

//Close JSON
});

//Close Function
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: in order to stop making and appending things, I made an unique HTML string that is going to be appended.

```
new_chat_string = '<div id="chat_'+from+'_lp" class="chat_box hidden_box clickable_box"><div id="'chat_+from+'_nick" class="chat_name">'+from+'</div><ul id="chat_'+from+'_txt" class="chat_txt"><li id="' + msg_id + '">'+ msg_txt+'</li></ul></div>';

$("#boxes").append(new_chat_string);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't $().click() work on <li> generated by pageinit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068879/why-doesnt-click-work-on-li-generated-by-pageinit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use class instead of id

```
<div id="chat_sender_lp" class="chat_box hidden_box clickable_box sender-click"
```

then

```
$('.hidden_box.sender-click').live('click', function(){
   $(this).slideToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: But what I want to, is that when I click **ONLY** on a __.hiden_box__ element it shows and viceversa. What's supposed to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
$("#boxes").append('<div id="chat_'+from+'_lp" class="chat_box hidden_box clickable_box" ><div id="name">'+from+'</div><ul id="chat_'+from+'_txt" class="chat_txt"><li id="' + msg_id + '">'+ msg_txt+'</li></ul></div>');
```

Add the event handler for the inserted element:

```
$('#chat_'+from+'_lp').click(function() { showChat(this)  })
```

"this" passes a DOM reference to itself.

Keep in mind that you're adding: `<div id="name">` every time. IDs must be unique. Use a class name instead.

**EDIT:**

Appending to the DOM is really quite slow. It's actually more efficient to build up your HTML as a string and just insert it in one go. Also, you only really need to stick and ID on the wrapping element. Everything else can be derived from that using a jQuery selector. It helps you write much cleaner code.

Here's the string you need to append:

```
'<div id="chat_'+msg_id+'" class="chat_box hidden_box clickable_box">
<div class="chat_name">'+from+'</div><ul class="chat_txt"><li>
<a href="javascript://">'+msg_txt+'</a></li></ul></div>'
```

If you wanted to select chat name later, you'd use: `$('chat_1 .chat_name').html()`

It also makes more semantic sense to hook up your click handler to an A tag. So you'd use:

```
$('#chat_'+msg_id).find('a').click(function() {showChat(this);});
```

The code is a lot cleaner and easier to follow this way. I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the main use is not understood. I want to make the same as Facebook chat, it checks from a JSON file the latest messages received (but that havent been read) and it appends it to an ul. This ul is in a box with the name, just as in Facebook, and I want the function that when I click on namebar, it closes and viceversa. I can make the box show and add new msgs but I can't make that function of show/hide. I'm writing it and I will clean the code later but want to make this work fist. Thank you very much for your help and I will really appreciate you help me again. Thanks!!!.