# Performance difference between jQuery's .live('click', fn) and .click(fn)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I love the new live event in jQuery 1.3.  The question I have is the performance of this event.  I know the advantages of using live over click/bind('click') but is there a performance hit for using it over click/bind('click')?

If not, why would you ever use click or bind('click')?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748076/using-live-benefits-similar-to-bind

Comment: I think they are different questions as this one relates solely to performance differences and not in general.

Comment: @MacAnthony: read the accepted answer to that question, it delves into the performance characteristics of `live` and `bind`. That's why I Dup'd this: it has been answered already.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link.  Didn't seem to find it when searching earlier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If not, why would you ever use click
>   or bind('click')?

Because [$.live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) has some significant disadvantages

> - Live events do not bubble in the traditional manner and <strike>**cannot be
>     stopped using stopPropagation**</strike> *(This changed in jquery 1.4.4)* or
>     stopImmediatePropagation. For example,
>     take the case of two click events -
>     one bound to "li" and another "li a".
>     Should a click occur on the inner
>     anchor BOTH events will be triggered.
>     This is because when a
>     $("li").bind("click", fn); is bound
>     you're actually saying "Whenever a
>     click event occurs on an LI element -
>     or inside an LI element - trigger this
>     click event." To stop further
>     processing for a live event, fn must
>     return false.
> - Live events currently only work when used against a selector. For
>     example, this would work: $("li
>     a").live(...) but this would not:
>     $("a", someElement).live(...) and
>     neither would this:
>     $("a").parent().live(...).

Comment: Also certain events cannot be captured by .live()

Comment: live() supports stopProgation since 1.4.4

Comment: @Kevin Just remember that this question AND answer are both over three years old at the time that I write this.

Answer (score 2):

See [this](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/432a0d9caae734db).

As for why you would ever use click or bind instead of live, the answer is because you don't need the extra functionality.