# Trouble adding event listeners via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I have a function which loops to create multiple HTML objects. Each time an object is created, I want to add an `onClick` function listener to that object so that I can trigger a function when each one is clicked.

What's the best way to do this?

Here's the code which creates my objects:

```
    RenderMultipleChoice:function()
{
    this.c = paper.rect(this.x, this.y, this.shapeWidth, this.shapeHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider to use [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) instead of adding a click listener to each created element. Then you only have one event listener on a parent, and see what element the event bubbled from. It will also magically work for elements created in the future.

jQuery has two methods to handle this for you:

- [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) - bind event listener to the body element (has disadvantages)
- [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) - bind event listener to the (parent)elements you specify (better performance)

Example:

```
$("#parent").delegate(".child", "click", RenderMultipleChoice);
```

live is an awesome function, but you should be aware of it's disadvantages:

[Performance difference between jQuery's .live('click', fn) and .click(fn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368223/performance-difference-between-jquerys-liveclick-fn-and-clickfn)

http://paulirish.com/2010/on-jquery-live/

Comment: I was unaware of event delegation until now, thanks very much for suggesting this. Looks like the way to go for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) or [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Assuming paper.rect returns a DOM element:

```
if(this.c.addEventListener)
{
  this.c.addEventListener("click", listenerFunction, false);
}
else 
{
  this.c.attachEvent("onclick", listenerFunction);
}
```

There are libraries to abstract this away.

Comment: actually you need to use both if you are going to have some sort of cross browser compatibility.