# jQuery forms and a hrefs

Tags: jquery, forms

So i wanted to make some pretty buttons like http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html and everything is working fine.  I wanted my forms to be able to be submitted with these sexy buttons.

So i started to use jQuery to handle all my "a" click actions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function() {
        alert("a");
        var a = $(this);
        var id = a.attr("id");
        switch (id) {
            case "formSubmit":
                a.parents("form:first").submit();
                return false;
});
```

one more question... How do i get that code above to be highlighted in javascript?  or any code like formating?  Sorry for the crappy spaces, the second i find out how, i will edit it.

I got distracted and forgot to ask the original question.  Now with jQuery it is easy to add in new information through $.post and other information.  HOW do i add in a new a href link so that the `$("a").click` catches it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler to handler clicks on new and future elements by replacing this:

```
$("a").click(function() {
```

With this:

```
$("a").live("click", function() {
```

This way a handler on `document` listens for clicks from `<a>` elements to bubble up...which happens for current and new elements.

Comment: let me give that a try and ill let you know!

Comment: 2 hours trying different things... no success<br>5 minutes on stack overflow... great success!!!

Comment: @Michael yes, there's a performance hit because of the way .live() binds from the root of the document (essentially a huge catch all on the 'click' event, then tries to match the selector pattern). It's always better to re-attach events when you update the dom instead. Live is just a very easy way to capture an event without having to worry about dom updates. Always avoid if possible.

Comment: +1 for a short & sweet explanation on how `.live()` works. :)

Comment: @Michael - there can be a slight one initially if you have *lots* of elements (still, nothing you can notice, not even close), you *can* do `$(document.body).delegate("a", "click", function() {` to be even cheaper.

Comment: more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368223/performance-difference-between-jquerys-liveclick-fn-and-clickfn

Comment: @Ben - This is very bad false information you're giving, there are alternative methods and `.live()` doesn't necessarily attach to `document`, it *by default* attaches to `document`, there's a clear distinction there.  It's not "always better" to reattach events, binding a `.live()` handler once is thousands of time cheaper (even with the selector cost per click) than binding a handler to thousands of elements individually...when you won't likely even use most of those handlers.

Comment: Whats the difference betwixt <code>$(document.body).delegate("a", "click", function() {</code> and <code>live()</code>

Comment: ahh.. i am no good at this commenting thing ;) how do i make comments with code within them?

Comment: @Michael - Use backticks, the difference is the `$("a")` selector to find the elements doesn't run off the bat, since that result set is wasted it's wasteful to run it.

Comment: @Ben - That link is *very* outdated, and so is the information, though it was never really accurate to begin with, `.live()` has always accepted a context.

Comment: @Michael Only inline markdown allowed in comments, and only a small subset of it. `**bold**`, `\`code\``, `*italics*`, `[link text](http://www.google.com)`

Comment: So i have a followup question. in the `a.parents("form:first").submit();` section of code, it should call the submit action of the form.  i also have code that does '$("form").submit(function() {'  But it is not being caught by anything.  Is there something wrong as well? I tried '$("form").live("submit", function() {' and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

`.click()` only binds your handler to already existing elements. To bind to any elements, whether they exist now or will exist later, you can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). For the sake of simplicity, we'll use `.live()`. The first parameter to `.live()` is a string, the event you wish to bind your handler to. The second parameter is your handler function.

Just change what you have to something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").live("click", function() {
  alert("a");
  var a = $(this);
  var id = a.attr("id");
  switch (id) {
   case "formSubmit":
   a.parents("form:first").submit();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: You should just note it as `.live()`, not `$.live()`, same for delegate, since these aren't static methods on the `jQuery` object.