# jQuery $(this).remove() not working after append

Tags: jquery, append

I have a div with `class="tags"` with one predefined hyperlink.

```
<div class="tags">
     <a href="#">myLink</a>
</div>
```

And I have function to remove that hyperlink if user clicks on it.

```
$('.tags a').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
    return false;
});
```

And this works with predefined hyperlinks.
If I add another links with the help of jQuery (after the page is loaded)

```
$('.tags').append('<a href="#">newLink</a>');
```

Function to remove hyperlink (on click) won't be called on these, added links. How to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the live-function:

```
$(".tags a").live("click", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Because you are adding the links after the initial load, the standard click event won't be binded to the dynamic added links.

Comment: **Note** that [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) has been depreciated since 1.7. It's advisable to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) from now on. The translated call would be `$(document).on('click', '.tags a', function () { /* foo */ });`

Comment: Thanks. Should I use it on all my clicks/similar actions or only when really needed?

Comment: For the performance, look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047193/liveclick-and-performance

I personally prefer to use the click-event and only use the live-event if I really need it, as it is clear that there will be dynamic added elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your click event only attached to current dom element not to future element.If you want to add this event to all element include future then you have to use live event in jquery.
http://jsfiddle.net/6cGvt/

Comment: **Note** that [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) has been depreciated since 1.7. It's advisable to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) from now on. The translated call would be `$(document).on('click', '.tags a', function () { /* foo */ });`

Comment: Yup,...For latest version in jquery .you have to use ON method