# Hide the Jquery notification bar

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery to display notification at the top of my webpage. I am using the following function to display the notification bar -

```
function myBar(message) {
    $("<div />", { class: 'mybar', text: message, id: 'mymsg' }).hide().prependTo("body")
      .slideDown('slow');
}
```

And in `$(document).ready(function(){` I am calling the `myBar("my message");`, with appropriate css. It is displaying the bar as required.

Now I want to hide the bar when one clicks on the bar. For that I am trying this

```
$("#mymsg").click(function() {
     $(this).remove();
})
```

But this is not working as such. Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Comment: See this [jQuery $(this).remove() not working after append](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665646/jquery-this-remove-not-working-after-append)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your div doesn't yet exist when you add the event handler, the jQuery set `$("#mymsg")` is empty and no event handler is added.

You could use `on` instead :

```
$(document.body).on('click', "#mymsg", function() {
     $(this).remove();
});
```

Or, if you prefer, you could bind the event when you add the div :

```
function myBar(message) {
    $("<div />", { class: 'mybar', text: message, id: 'mymsg' }).click(function(){
       $(this).remove();
    }).hide().prependTo("body").slideDown('slow');
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of same kind of problem but was not sure how to tackle that. 
Its working fine now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads the message element doesn't exist yet in the DOM, so the click event handler is not bound to the element.

Since this seems to be a one-time message, consider chaining the event handler directly in the creating function. For example:

```
function myBar(message) {
    $("<div />", {
        class: 'mybar',
        text: message,
        id: 'mymsg'
    }).hide().prependTo("body").slideDown('slow').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```