# need to save 'this' value in JQuery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am saving the 'this' on click of a li in a Jquery cookie, but in place of saving it's value it is saving its type :

```
     $("ul > li").live('click', function () {
    $.cookie("liEvent", this, { expires: 100, path: "/" });
alert(this);
    }
```

The value of 'this'coming is : [object HTMLLIElement] while it should come as as li element which is inside ul.

Please help.

Comment: because cookies don't store objects,rather string representation of objects.

Comment: if you want the contents of the li you want `this.innerHTML`

Comment: but this has the html inside li tag, what if I need to include li as well. $($(this.html()).parent() is not working

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of advanced to explain, but `this` is a **pointer, and not an actual value**. If you want to be able to access your `li` element in another function, or similar, you can just pass on its `id` attribute, or similar.

Comment: Okay, I need the current li clicked. how to get its value then?

Comment: @user2614405, use `this.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You can't really save objects to cookies - Because there would be too much recursion and the resulting value would be huge. you would need to implement some kind of serialisation, or store an identifier that you can use to reload the value.

I assume that if you are using cookies you plan on refreshing the page? In which case the `this` keyword would do you no good - as the reference to the object would change.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the value of li into cookie you should use

```
      $(this).html()
```

Also there are certain disadvantages to using .live () ... hence i would recommend you use .on() instead.

```
     $("ul").on('click', "li", function () {..
```

The problems related to .live() have been discussed here [jQuery disadvantages of consistently using 'live'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433051/jquery-disadvantages-of-consistently-using-live)

Comment: I am using JQ1.6 so stuck with live only. & this gives the html inside li tag, what if I need to include li as well. $($(this.html()).parent() is not working

Comment: Is there any specific information as attributes associated with the li?

Comment: $($(this.html()).parent() will definitely not work as it will include all <li>'s . i would suggest u use '<li> ' + $(this).html() + '</li>'. And if you have any specific attributes associated with the <li> .. retrieve them and associate with the string yourself