# How do I make this code work for each click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, jquery-events

I have `h3` block's and on click of each of the block I am showing the section associated with it. It is actually something like accordion(hide and collapse). I have also given a drop icon to the `h3` tags, means that when the block is opened  the `h3` should have a dropicon pointing downwards while others `h3` should have there dropocons towards right. I am controlling this behaviour using `backgroundPosition`. I am using the jQuery visible condition to see if the particular block is visible then give its drop icon one background position and to the rest other. It works fine but only for first click. It doesn't work for second click; can somebody explain why? Here is my code:

```
if($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $(this).css({'backgroundPosition':'0px 14px'});
}
else {
    $("h3").css({'backgroundPosition':'0px -11px'});
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
$("h3").click(function() {          
    $(".tabs").hide();
    $(this).next().show();

    if($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).css({'backgroundPosition':'0px 14px'});
    } else {
        $("h3").css({'backgroundPosition':'0px -11px'});
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you using a click-handler at all? Or just an `if`? What, in this context, is `$(this)`?

Comment: In your else statement you do $("h3") instead of $(this)

Comment: It could have something to do with you not using $(this) for the second one (you have $("h3") instead).

Comment: @DavidThomas: off course I am using a click handler, plz see updated code

Comment: @Mike, have you tried changing the `$("h3")` part to `$(this)` yet?

Comment: @kiswa: gave  a try but didnt work

Comment: Can you post the html for your *h3* ?

Comment: I would recommend simply adding/removing a CSS class to an active element.  `.addClass('active')` and `.removeClass('active')`.  Then you can attach those `backgroundPosition` CSS to that class and you can simply use `.hasClass('active')` for conditional checking.

Comment: I Agreed with @Fozzyuw, you could use Class in the h3 too, so you can avoid any kind of trouble with h3 element. Usually you are gonna use .css() when you are using animate().

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the whole block in a div it might make traversing easier.

Html:

```
<div class="drop-block">
<h3>Click this</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Drop</li>
        <li>it</li>
        <li>like</li>
        <li>it's</li>
        <li>hot</li>
   </ul>
</div>​
```

Jquery:

```
var dropper = $('.drop-block'); 
$(dropper).find('h3').click(function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(dropper).find('ul').toggle();
});​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gNNwQ/)

Answer (score 1):

I Belive that you are looking for [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

So it will be something like this:

```
$(element).live('click', function(){
    if($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).css({'backgroundPosition':'0px 14px'});
    }
    else {
        $("h3").css({'backgroundPosition':'0px -11px'});
    }
}
```

Comment: jQuery `.live()` is useful if you are dynamically adding/removing event driving HTML.  Ie. If you have a list of H3 and you just use `.click()`, only the H3 items currently in the document will get the event function attached to it.  If you dynamically add more H3 later on, they will not have the event code associated with them.  If you use `.live()`, jQuery will attach the event handler each time something is dynamically added.  I would use `.click()` unless you need dynamic usage.  I would expect extra cost to use `.live()`.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368223/performance-difference-between-jquerys-liveclick-fn-and-clickfn) is a great link that talk about click and live('click'). Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing the css of them, make a css class "open" (or similar), and then add / remove the class on the click to open / close.

It is much easier to debug by checking for the existence of a class than it is to check the css properties of something in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Better make a class name for each situation and easly handle the action

```
$('h3').on('click', function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
     $(this).removeClass('opened');
   }
   else {
      $(this).addClass('opened');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to bind click events to the `h3` elements and toggle the visibility of  the child elements:

```
$(function(){
    $("h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".tabs").toggle();
    });
});
```

Example markup:

```
<h3>Item 1</h3>
<div class="tabs">
    <h4>Option 1</h4>
    <h4>Option 2</h4>
</div>
<h3>Item 2</h3>
<div class="tabs">
    <h4>Option 1</h4>
    <h4>Option 2</h4>
</div>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JkzfX/3/) to demonstrate.

Comment: makes no difference, I think the DOM traversal is not happening properly, for h3 tags

Comment: Can you post some of your markup so we can see how you're building the accordion?

Comment: Exactly the same way as you suggested above. The only difference is you have ul li, and I have div with class = "tabs"

Comment: I updated my example, and included a jsFiddle to show you that it works. If it's not working for you, there's probably an issue somewhere else in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'h3', function(e) {          
    $(".tabs").hide('slow'); 
    $(this).css({'backgroundPosition':'0px 14px'});

    if(!$(this).next().is(':visible'))
    {
        $("h3").css({'backgroundPosition':'0px -11px'});
        $(this).next().show('slow');
    }
});
```

> You can remove 'slow' from show/hide if animation is not required

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BY2Sy/2/).